# Why is my form.validate_on_submit() not adding the data into my database?

Tags: python, flask

When I am using `if request.method == 'POST':` the data is adding. But if I use `if form.validate_on_submit():` there is no error but it is not adding into the database.

routes.py:

```
@app.route("/expenses/<int:budget_id>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def expenses(budget_id):
    form = ExpenseForm()
    budget = Budgets.query.get(budget_id)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        budget_expense = Expenses(categories=form.categories.data, category_cost=form.cost.data, budget_id=budget.id)
        db.session.add(budget_expense)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('expenses', budget_id=budget.id))
    posted_expenses = Expenses.query.all()
    return render_template("expenses.html", budget=budget, form=form, posted_expenses=posted_expenses)
```

forms.py:

```
class ExpenseForm(FlaskForm):
    categories = SelectField('Select Expense', choices=[('', '-----'),('Food', 'Food'), 
                            ('Clothes', 'Clothes'), ('Bills/Payments', 'Bills/Payments'), 
                            ('Transportation', 'Transportation'), ('Miscellaneous', 'Misclellaneous')])
    cost = IntegerField('Cost', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=0, max=1000000)])
    submit = SubmitField('Add')
```

format of my form `<form action="{{ url_for('expenses', budget_id=budget.id )}}" method="POST">`

Can someone explain to me why it is not adding into the database?

Comment: are you sure your form is valid and the validate_on_submit() branch is being called? You need to display the form errors

Comment: @user2682863, yes, because when I am using request.method == 'POST' it actually adding it into the database and I can query it. I just don't know why it is not working when using validate_on_submit().

Comment: import `flash` from flask and the call `flash(str(form.errors))` at the top of the function or just log or print `str(form.errors)`

Comment: @user2682863 I tried to use form.errors and also flashing when the requirement data did not met and there is nothing showing. Maybe I don't get any error from my form.

Comment: `validate_on_submit` just checks that each field is valid and that it is a post request

Comment: I just used `{% if form.errors %}`, I forgot to use this earlier. Now the error is I forgot the `{{ form.csrf_token }}` inside the form.

Comment: ok, you should probably delete the question then